# Basics of Statistics and Linear Regression. Law of iterated expectations (LIE). Solving a problem.

Tags: statistics, problem-solving

I am studying economics and I am confused by this problem
Consider the three random variables (S, X, Y ) for which we have :
Given data:
X: 0 0 0 1 1 1
S: 1 2 3 1 2 3
Pr(X, S): 0.1 0.36 0.14 0.10 0.24 0.06
E(Y|X, S): 10 15 20 20 25 30

I need to Use the Law of Iterated Expectations to verify the following properties:
a) E(Y ) = E[E(Y | X)]
b) E(Y | X) = E[E(Y | S, X)| X]
c) Let Z = f(S)=1 if S ≥ 2
0 else. Show that E(Y |Z) = E[E(Y | S)|Z]

I tried solving it but for a) I get 19 for the left hand side(LHS) and 9.44 for the RHS. I'm not sure if that is correct and I have no idea for the rest of them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).